# Abrir un archivo PDF desde PHP/Javascript bloquea el uso de la pagina temporalmente

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy teniendo problemas para lograr que la pagina web no se "congele" por un tiempo mientras carga el archivo solicitado,

-PHP: openFile

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="miFile.pdf"');
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("miFile.pdf"));
readfile('miFile.pdf');
```

Del lado de javascript he intentado varias cosas, desde un simple `window.open()`

```
const url = "/open-pdf/openFile.php?file=miFile.pdf";
window.open(url);
```

Tratando de forzar una funcion asyncrona:

```
function openUrlAsync(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.open(url);
        resolve();
    });
}
async function openFile(url){
    await openUrlAsync(url);
}
```

En lugar de hacerlo mediante un `window.open()` mandarlo a un `iframe`:

```
function openUrlAsync(url, fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const pdfPreview = document.getElementById('pdf-preview');
        pdfPreview.querySelector('iframe').src = url;
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Y siempre se comporta igual, al abrir el archivo funciona y se carga tanto en una pestaña nueva como en el iFrame, el problema que durante esos segundos de carga, todo el sitio deja de responder, si hago cualquier otra acción pareciera que se pone en cola esperando a que el archivo termine de mostrarse antes de continuar con la siguiente operación,

¿existe alguna forma de evitar ese comportamiento y que funcione como una función asíncrona o como hilo independiente, para que la pagina no se congele solo por eso?

Comment: y el error te sale algo???

Comment: No hay error, "todo funciona bien", excepto por que javascript o el sitio dejan de responder a otros eventos mientras cargue el archivo, y dependiendo del tamaño suele ser casi un minuto para archivos grandes, por lo que la usabilidad se va por los suelos. Solo quiero evitar que la pagina se congele esperando a que cargue por completo el archivo.

Comment: es normal que mientras se carga un archivo la interface grafica del sitio se detenga y deje de ser interactiva, esto sucede mas a menudo si tiene un antivirus como ESET... tambien es normal que ocurra si estas enviado datos al backend... a menos que lo hagas mediante socket o ajax o algun metodo interactivo que te permita continuar interactuando con el sitio.

Comment: ¿Entonces no hay nada que pueda hacer? No me quiero comparar con otros sitios pero he analizado el comportamiento de servicios como oneDrive o Drive y no sucede lo mismo, mientras esta cargando la visualización puedo hacer otras acciones.
He probado ahora con `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` pero sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Comment: eso sigue siendo intrusivo...